# Target a specific DIV with jQuery to replace HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a WordPress Loop rendering Forms with which you can edit Posts (so instead of Posts, I return the Forms, one form each post)
That Loop is rendered on a WordPress default Page.

The Rendered Forms are all wrapped in a Div "div id="mydiv""

Those Div's increase their unique ID "mydiv", once per Form rendered, means, first Form has ID "mydiv", second Form in loop has ID "mydiv2" etc.

*But that does not really matter in my question here.*

I use this below jQuery to submit the Form(s) and after the form is submitted, I would like to replace the form(s) with the Post which has been edited.

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("[id^=cred_form_1614]").ajaxForm(function(data) {
if (data.length > 0) {
    jQuery('.page').empty();
  jQuery('.page').html(data);
}
});
});
```

The issue is, targeting "page", I replace *all* forms with *a single post*.

If I target "mydiv" (no matter which one), the form(s) keep(s) displaying, it's not replaced with the edited post.

So, question:

How can I use above code to target the specific DIV's (mydiv, mydiv2, mydiv3, etc)?

I want that the form wrapped in "mydiv" is replaced by the post which this form edits.
Form in "mydiv2" must be kept displaying, as long I don't submit it.
Then, if submitted, also "mydiv2" must be replaced with the Post this form edits.
And so on.

It works great as long I replace the entire page. That means, the code is basically working.

But, I need to target specific DIV's.

Is this possible?

where is ma (t)error?

I tried with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("[id^=cred_form_1614]").ajaxForm(function(data) {
if (data.length > 0) {
    jQuery('.mydiv').empty();
  jQuery('.mydiv').html(data);
}
});
});
```

And made sure, the first form in loop is wrapped in "mydiv".
I also tried to restrict my loop to one rendered Form, but as long I target a specific DIV in my jQuery (not .page) then the code breaks

No successful results!
It just keeps displaying the Form(s)

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Its hard to understand you. Rewrite your question and clearly ask state what is wrong and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Could you post your HTML, please?  I suspect your error is that you are using a . rather than a # to represent an ID selector.  If you post the HTML, I can check that this is the case.

Comment: you refer to the page's html where the form renders, or the form's html? also, not sure what is not clear about my question? I need to target a div, I can only target div id="page" with above code, div like div id="mydiv" don't "work"

Comment: why should . be wrong? it works in div id="page" (.page) so it should also work with div id="myid" (.myid)? will try to change to #

Comment: OK, you are right. I need to use # instead of .

Comment: I added a link to the HTML of the page. It's huge :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/msS0CVV2

Comment: and obviously my next question now is the one: "How can I increase the target ID in jQuery" (so jQuery will correct target mydiv1, mydiv2, depending which form I submit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly.

If you want to target an element by id you use the following syntax: `$('#id')`.

Comment: I agree, that works. but why does div id="page" use .page, and not #page?

See my above code, that works fine. using #in other divs, works, but I don't understand why?

Comment: `$('.page')` returns all elements with the class "page". 

I suggest that you modify your mark up and add a class to the wrapping element to make it easier to target ("formContainer" for example).

`jQuery("[id^=cred_form_1614]").ajaxForm(function(data) {
var $self = $(this);
var replaceTarget = $self.closest('.formContainer');

if (data.length > 0) {
    jQuery(replaceTarget).empty().html(data);}
});
});`

I also suggest that you target your forms using a class name instead of the `[id^=cred_form_1614]` selector.

Comment: humm, I'll try that. but I need to use [id^=cred_form_1614] because i have many forms, in the loop. if i have a unique id (the same for all forms) i would target all forms at once, and that is not what I want. but i'll try your suggestion...

Comment: I am not sure I understand as well CLASS is <div class="my class"> ID is <div id="myid"> so .page should NOT work, as my div I target is a ID page, not CLASS page .... OR I am completly out of scope...